# What is this inequality stating?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$[(4x-12):4+7-x]>0$$

Is this set notation? Or is this a ratio?

I am not looking for the actual solution. I just want to know how to correctly interpret what the problem is asking.

Comment: $[\frac{4x-12}{4}+7-x]>0$ which is true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What happen to the 4?

Comment: $x:4$ or $x\div 4$ mean $\frac{x}{4}$. It's a division.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. You can post this as an actual answer and I'll check you off and +1 your answer for points if you want.

Comment: Sometimes square brackets are used as an alternative to parenthesis, but they are also used for "largest integer less or equal to". Or the source might be using some weird convention. Hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\div 4$ or $x:4$ or $\frac{x}{4}$ means the same thing. So your inequality becomes $$\frac{4x-12}{4}+7-x>0$$
$$x-3+7-x>0$$ which is always true.